# cannot access virtual functions in an instance retrieved using CONTAINING_RECORD

Tags: vtable

I am using windows programming with C++ and have below code:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Func1 () {}
    void         Func2 () {}
}

class B : public A
{
public:
    __override virtual void Func1 ()  {}
}
```

I made a double linked list of B objects using LIST_ENTRY and tried to visit an element in this list in below way:

```
LIST_ENTRY  * pEntry; // I got this pointer using RemoveHeadList
A           * pA;
pA = CONTAINING_RECORD (pEntry, A, m_le);
pA->Func2 ();         // works fine
pA->Func1 ();         // Access violation
```

As you see, the pointer retrieved using CONTAINING_RECORD cannot call a virtual function. What could be wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the code, `CONTAINING_RECORD` is returning an invalid pointer. Show us the code for it. Func2 wprks just by chance, because is not dependant on the this pointer, but is nevertheless ilegal.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247270/access-violation-exception-when-calling-a-method) pointed me to the right direction and I found the memory of object A retrieved by CONTAINING_RECORD has been overwritten before I visit this element. Thanks for your input.